# How to write postgres query

Tags: sql, postgresql, jpa

I am new to sql. How can I write query in postgresql for below statement.

```
select * 
FROM t1 
where (error_id = (123 or 456 or 789) and message_id = 100) 
   or (error_id = 111 and message_id=222)
```

Comment: I believe a better place to start your PostgreSQL journey is by going a little through tutorials and the documentation

Comment: Most likely you need some documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/index.html

Comment: You should use the `IN` keyword when you're checking for multiple values: `error_id IN (123 or 456 or 789)`.

Comment: @lemon do I need to use a subquery?

Comment: @BhanuMittal: Why don't you try to learn SQL instead of random guess work? https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

Comment: @BhanuMittal Check Isolated's answer, yet Frank's link is quite useful, you should definitely go that path before coming on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned in the comments, you should read up on sql and syntax in the postgres documenation. You can also get some practice by using db-fiddle sites, where you can create your own tables, populate them and write queries against them.

The proper query would look like this, where you use `IN` when including more than one value.

```
select * 
from t1 
where (error_id in (123, 456, 789) and message_id = 100) 
   or (error_id = 111 and message_id=222)
```